# On Pointers and Dereferencing

Tags: c++

I've been working on learning C++ lately and picked up the book "C++ Through Game Programming". I'm on the chapter on Pointers and I've been presented an example that I have a question about. The code is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void badSwap(int x, int y);
void goodSwap(int* const pX, int* const pY);

int main()
{
    int myScore = 150;
    int yourScore = 1000;
    cout << "Original values\n";
    cout << "myScore: " << myScore << "\n";
    cout << "yourScore: " << yourScore << "\n\n";
    cout << "Calling badSwap()\n";
    badSwap(myScore, yourScore);
    cout << "myScore: " << myScore << "\n";
    cout << "yourScore: " << yourScore << "\n\n";
    cout << "Calling goodSwap()\n";
    goodSwap(&myScore, &yourScore);
    cout << "myScore: " << myScore << "\n";
    cout << "yourScore: " << yourScore << "\n";
    cin >> myScore;
    return 0;
}

void badSwap(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
void goodSwap(int* const pX, int* const pY)
{
    //store value pointed to by pX in temp
    int temp = *pX;
    //store value pointed to by pY in address pointed to by pX
    *pX = *pY;
    //store value originally pointed to by pX in address pointed to by pY
    *pY = temp;
}
```

In the goodSwap() function there's the line:

```
*pX = *pY;
```

Why would you dereference both sides of the assignment? Isn't that the equivalent of saying "1000 = 150"?

Comment: The expression `*pX = *pY` could be read as "the location of where `pX` is pointing will be assigned to the value of the location of where `pY` is pointing". It's basically the same as in the `badSwap` function where you have `x = y`, you wouldn't say it's equal to "1000 = 150" would you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why would you dereference both sides of the assignment? Isn't that the equivalent of saying "1000 = 150"?

No, just like the following:

```
int x = 1000;
int y = 150;

x = y;
```

is not the equivalent of saying "1000 = 150". You're assigning to the *object*, not to the value it presently contains.

The below is *precisely* the same (since the expression `*px` is an lvalue referring to the object `x`, and the expression `*py` is an lvalue referring to the object `y`; they're literally aliases, not some strange, disconnected version of the objects' numerical values):

```
int   x = 1000;
int   y = 150;
int* px = &x;
int* py = &y;

*px = *py;
```

Comment: So what is actually being stored at a memory location? As far as I can tell it's only a value. Is the variable that originally held the value also stored there?

Comment: @FireArrow5235: The variable _is_ the value. What difference do you perceive there to be between the two, in memory? An object is a region of storage: in this case, four or eight bytes containing a [probably] two's complement numerical value equal to `1000`. Your C++ program, when compiled, knows where these bytes are (because it put them there) and how to store and read from them. A "variable" is an abstract concept in C++ to allow you to refer to this block of bytes as an entity independent from whatever its location ends up being in memory at runtime.

Comment: Ok! I get it now. The difference was that I was under the impression that a memory location could ONLY store data pertaining to an integer (or other assigned data type) and absolutely nothing else. Therefore a variable and the value that a variable held were in 2 separate places. I didn't see x as being the integer that was held in the memory location.

Comment: @FireArrow5235: Well, yeah, memory _does_ only contain numbers. It's a sequence of bytes. Ones and zeroes. Those ones and zeroes encode the integers and floating-point values in your program*. The notion of types and variables and objects is an abstraction that doesn't even exist in your compiled program. It's provided in the syntax of higher-level languages like C++ for programmer convenience only! That's the entire purpose of such languages (and their compilers), actually: so that you do not have to fiddle with raw data at various memory locations all by yourself!

Comment: Your compiler is very clever and creates an executable that does a _lot_ of work to manage those bits and bytes and keep everything in the right place, according to the semantics described by your higher-level program. But it doesn't actually "store" types and variables anywhere; that logic is built into the program. It's inherent. _* (and, by composition, the more complex types that are built from them)_

Comment: Right! Until now I'd never had to think about everything I write in code not being explicitly held and read in memory somewhere. I completely understand now. For clarity... derereferencing essentially turns a pointer variable into a non-pointer variable right?

Comment: @FireArrow5235 Sort of more or less yes

Answer (score 0):

*px=*py means we are assigning the value not address, from address of py to address of px.

Comment: But wouldn't dereferencing pX set pX equal to a value and not a variable?

Comment: @FireArrow5235 In C++ a variable can hold address( memory location) then it is called a pointer variable. If a variable only holding a value not directly aadressing its memory location it is a non pointer variable.

Answer (score -1):

Skip the chapter of the book or buy another one:
there is no need of using plain pointers in C++ nowadays.

Also there is a [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function, that does the things C++isch.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please post it as such.